# Pop to viewcontroller Editing Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `ViewcontrollerA` as a form filling page and to perform a calculation I push a new `viewcontrollerB` now when I pop to `ViewcontrollerA` the existing contents are cleared

My code is

In viewcontroller A

```
JS_skill *skill_VC = [[JS_skill alloc] initWithNibName:@"JS_skill" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:skill_VC animated:NO];
```

In viewcontroller B

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Post your code for view controller a please

Comment: -(IBAction)button_JS_Skill:(id)sender
{
    JS_skill *skill_VC = [[JS_skill alloc] initWithNibName:@"JS_skill" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:skill_VC animated:NO];
}

Comment: I mean the whole code for your ViewController A so I can see how you have set things up.

Comment: That have too many lines

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    [self setup_VIEWS];
}

Comment: did you do some wrong settings in controllerA's viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method?

Comment: In setup View I had add code to show the initial page setup

Comment: -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}

Comment: STOP adding code in the comments. Please edit your question to include the code for your `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad` methods in `ViewController A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick option would be to save the values of the textfields in userDefaults before you push the viewcontroller. Then when you return to the viewController in viewWillAppear set the textfields back to what you have in userDefaults:

```
//Just before you push the viewController:
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:@"Example Name" forKey:@"nameTextField"];
[defaults setValue:@"Example Surname" forKey:@"surnnameTextField"];

//In ViewWillAppear:
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
textField.text = [defaults valueForKey:@"nameTextField"];
surnameField.text = [defaults valueForKey:@"surnnameTextField"];
```

Comment: This is one option, you have a different key set for each field - as shown with firstName, surnName, etc etc

Comment: Here when I pop the view controller Viewdidload is executed

Comment: view did load should only run once when you first load the view controller and then when you push away and then pop back it shouldn't run and only viewWillAppear should run? Is the view controller not  in memory/deallocated when you push away then?

Comment: What iOS you building for?

Comment: Slap on my face I found the error I set dealloc and set self.view = Nil